# how to add the table titles to a p:dataexporter file

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{exportarBean.encontroSalida}">
    <h:outputText value="Exportar información de la tabla salida" />
        <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="/imagenes/logo_csv.png" width="50" />
            <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tblSalida" fileName="SalidaRefacciones" pageOnly="false" />
        </h:commandLink>
</h:panelGrid>
```

But the exported csv does not have the table titles. Do you know how to add them to the file? What is missing in my code?

Help me please.

**Edit**

The table:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblSalida" var="sal" value="#{exportarBean.listaSalidas}" paginator="true" rows="50" paginatorPosition="both" rendered="#{exportarBean.opcionListar == 'salida'}">
    <p:column headerText="QR">
        <h:outputText value="#{sal.idRefaccion}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Equipo">
        <h:outputText value="#{sal.equipo}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Marca">
        <h:outputText value="#{sal.marca}" />
    </p:column>
    // More columns
 </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Post the table code aswell

Comment: @EmilKaminski Question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use header facet's, like this:

```
  <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="QR" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{sal.idRefaccion}" />
  </p:column>
```